# Having trouble getting MSAL Authorization Code workflow to work

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

I am building a desktop python application that uses the MSAL authorization code workflow by opening up a browser window for authentication. I keep getting back an invalid grant error (code 70000) for some accounts but not others when trying to get an authorization token. It seems to work just fine for the personal Microsoft account through which the application is registered in the Azure portal. It also works fine for my university account (a school Microsoft account), but not for other personal Microsoft accounts.

Through the Azure portal, the application is registered with the ability for all Microsoft accounts to work with it. The scopes listed there also match the scopes that I am requesting in the python application.

The authorize endpoint does return a valid looking authorization code, but then when I try to use that code to get a valid token, I get the error. More specifically, the message associated with the error says:
`AADSTS70000: The request was denied because one or more scopes requested are unauthorized or expired. The user must first sign in and grant the client application access to the requested scope.\r\nTrace ID: 6afddbd2-308e-44df-8640-976dc1c1f601\r\nCorrelation ID: bdb626d0-0a3d-4333-ac8f-b5ff510ca046\r\nTimestamp: 2022-07-24 18:50:23Z`

What might be causing this issue to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with the scopes I was providing to the authorization endpoint. The scopes `profile`, `openid`, and `offline_access` should be specified to allow some features of Microsoft's Graph API to function properly. In my case, it was the `offline_access` scope that did the trick. Also note that these scopes cannot be added to the authorization *token* request, at least through the Python MSAL library. These scopes need to be specified during the process of getting the authorization code only, not the token.